# A better way to flatten an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, flatten

I require the array keys to be maintained, with a number appended to the key to make it unique when flattening an array.

Example input:

```
$array = array(
    array("name"=>"bob", "age"=>32, "third_param"=>"something"),
    array("name"=>"ted", "age"=>57, "third_param"=>"something else"),
    array("name"=>"ned", "age"=>103, "third_param"=>"another something"),
);
```

Required output:

```
$array = array(
    "name-1"=>"bob", 
    "age-1"=>32, 
    "third_param-1"=>"something",
    "name-2"=>"ted", 
    "age-2"=>57, 
    "third_param-2"=>"something else",
    "name-3"=>"ned",
    "age-3"=>103, 
    "third_param-3"=>"another something"
);
```

I was able to figure out how to do it, but my solution is slow and messy. There has got to be a better way.

Here's my current function:

```
function flatten_array($array, $flat = array()) {
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        $k = strval($k);
        if(!is_array($v)){
            $i = 0;
            while(true){
                $i++;
                $key = $k."-".strval($i);
                if(!isset($flat[$key])) break;
            }
            $flat[$key] = $v;
        }else{
            $flat = flatten_array($v, $flat);
        }
    }
    return $flat;
}
```

Here's an example usage: http://3v4l.org/6QVj0/
(Hit the execute button, and then have a look at the "Performance" tab.

This takes a long time and has timed-out on me when testing it on real data, however it does produce the result I need. What can I do to this to make it quicker and not take up  so much memory?

Comment: Whatever you're doing I'm 99% positive that the original array is better.  Maybe expand on why you want to change it.

Comment: Sure. I'm working on a class that builds reports from a database in HTML table or CSV format. Some of the fileds hold ambiguous JSON data. In order to make the JSON easily readable in a table or CSV I need to flatten it. I've got that part figure out already.

Comment: @AbraCadaver you still 99% sure?

Comment: No, now I'm 100% sure.

Comment: @AbraCadaver elaborate. how would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$ar = array();

foreach ($array as $i => $items) {
   foreach ($items as $key => $value) {     
      $ar[$key.'-'.($i+1)] = $value;
   } 
}
```

Comment: it works great, much shorter than mine but not much of a performance boost. Was hoping to get all the performance parameters in the green. http://3v4l.org/vR1fE/perf#tabs

Comment: This doesn't work if the array is more than 2 dimensions. My arrays will typically be more than 2 dimensions. http://3v4l.org/C1JWk

Comment: Recursion would work fast in this case, but i'm not good with recursion. I tried to keep it simple.